# Using phpExcel to download xlsx file using Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, download, phpexcel

I'm writing a php web app to create and download an xlsx file, using Google App Engine:

```php
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheet(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 4);

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

When I run this app locally, it creates and downloads a new xlsx file correctly, but it fails when deployed since Google App Engine currently does not support 'php://output' ([feature request here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10298))

'php://temp' and 'php://memory' *are* supported, but I'm not finding much documentation on how/if I can write and download a file using those options. Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Most obvious answer would be to save to a temporary file, use readfile(), then delete the temporary file

Comment: You could potentially write to GCS and remove the file afterwards. Or you could write to php://temp, then readfile('php://temp')