# PhpExcel on Google App Engine Error: Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Tags: php, google-app-engine, phpexcelreader

I am trying to parse an XLSX file with PhpExcel on Google App Engine. When I run the script it gives me this error: Invalid or uninitialized Zip object. I've read other questions but they don't seem to help ( [PHPExcel Google App Engine not saving file for Excel2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32343557/phpexcel-google-app-engine-not-saving-file-for-excel2007) ),( [Using phpExcel to download xlsx file using Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511385/using-phpexcel-to-download-xlsx-file-using-google-app-engine) ), ( [Google App Engine trowing error for PHPExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336544/google-app-engine-trowing-error-for-phpexcel) ). I have tried to write the file to the temporary folder (sys_get_temp_dir()) but it gives me the same error when i read from there.

```
        $inputFileName = $this->Anexos_model->get_path($id_anexo);

    $temp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'TMP_');
    file_put_contents($temp, file_get_contents($inputFileName));

    var_dump($temp);

    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($temp);
```

It gives me this:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: ZipArchive::getFromName(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object

Filename: Reader/Excel2007.php

Comment: please share a minimal example of the code you're using. That way, the users of Stack overflow can help out...

Comment: I pasted an example to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked if zlib is active on your php environment ? Check also your memory_limit if the XLSX is too big.

Comment: Yes, it is active by default on Google App Engine Environment.

Comment: I think the memory limit is ignored by app engine. It uses my instance memory to process data. Thanks anyway.